# Problemas con jQuery y javascipt al consultar

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

Buen dia estoy desarrollando una aplicacion en php, el problema es que al realizar la consulta no me encuentra el dato que si esta alojado en la base de datos, estoy utilizando jQuery y una funcion en javascript que me redirecciona la consuta. este es mi codigo.

```
    function consultarPaciente(){
        url = "index.php?accion=consultarPaciente&documento="+$("#asignarDocumento")
                .attr("value");
        $("#paciente").load(url);
    }


    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8" content="text/html" http-equiv="Content-Type">
            <title>Sistema Gestion Odontologica</title>
            <link href="Vista/css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
            <script type="text/javascript" src="Vista/jquery/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script> 
            <script type="text/javascript" src="Vista/js/script.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="contenedor">
                <div id="encabezado">
                    <img src="Vista/imagenes/odontologia.png" width="100%" height="150px" >
                </div>
                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a href="index.php">Inicio</a></li>
                    <li class="activa"><a href="index.php?accion=asignar">Asignar Cita</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?accion=consultar">Consultar Cita</a></li>
                    <li><a href="index.php?accion=cancelar">Cancelar Cita</a></li>
                </ul>
                <div id="contenido">
                    <h2 style="width:100%">Asignar Cita</h2>
                    <form id="frmAsignar" method="POST" action="index.php?accion=guardarCita">
                        <table>
                            <tr>
                                <td>Documento del Paciente</td>
                                <td><input type="text" name="asignarDocumento" id="asignarDocumento"></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="2">
                                <input type="button" name="asignarConsultar" value="Consultar" id="asignarConsultar" onclick="consultarPaciente()">
                                </td>
                            </tr>
```

tengo una clase controlador que maneja el siguiente formato.

```
    public function consultarPaciente($doc) {
        $gestorCita = new GestorCita();
        $result = $gestorCita->consultarPaciente($doc);
        require_once 'Vista/html/consultarPaciente.php'; 
    }
```

la clase gestorcita es la siguiente:

```
    # metodo consultar paciente
public function consultarPaciente($doc){
    $conexion = new Conexion();
    $conexion->abrir();

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM Pacientes WHERE pacIdentificacion = '$doc' ";

    $conexion->consultar($sql);
    $result = $conexion->obtenerResult();
    $conexion->cerrar();

    return $result;
}
```

y todo esto me redirecciona a consultarPaciente.php:

```
    <?php
if($result->num_rows > 0){
?>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Identificacion</td>
        <td>Nombre</td>
        <td>Sexo</td>
    </tr>
    <?php
    $fila = $result->fetch_object();
    ?> 
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $fila->pacIdentificacion ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila->pacNombres." ".$fila->pacApellidos; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $fila->pacSexo; ?></td>  
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
}
else{
?>

     El Paciente no se encuentra en la base de datos.<br/>
    <input type="button" name="ingPaciente" value="Ingresar Paciente" id="ingPaciente" onclick="ingPaciente()">
<?php
}
?>
```

Esta es la pagina principal index.php donde llamo todas las acciones del sistema.

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    require_once 'Controlador/Controlador.php';
    require_once 'Modelo/GestorCita.php';
    require_once 'Modelo/Cita.php';
    require_once 'Modelo/Paciente.php';
    require_once 'Modelo/Conexion.php';

    $controlador = new Controlador();

    if(isset($_GET['accion'])){

        if($_GET['accion'] == 'asignar'){
            $controlador->verPagina('Vista/html/asignar.php');
        }
        elseif($_GET['accion'] == 'consultar'){
            $controlador->verPagina('Vista/html/consultar.php');
        }
        elseif ($_GET['accion'] == 'cancelar') {
            $controlador->verPagina('Vista/html/cancelar.php');
        }
        elseif ($_GET['accion'] == 'guardarCita') {
           $controlador->agregarCita($_POST['asignarDocumento'], $_POST['medico'],
                   $_POST['fecha'], $_POST['hora'], $_POST['consultorio']); 
        }
        elseif($_GET['accion'] == 'consultarCita'){
            $controlador->consultarCitas($_POST['consultarDocumento']);
        }
        elseif ($_GET['accion'] == 'cancelarCita') {
            $controlador->cancelarCita($_POST['cancelarDocumento']);
        }
        elseif ($_GET['accion'] == 'consultarPaciente') {
            $controlador->consultarPaciente($_GET['documento']);
        }
        else{
            $controlador->verPagina('Vista/html/inicio.php');
        }
    }
    else{
        $controlador->verPagina('Vista/html/inicio.php');
    }

    ?>
</body>
```

el paciente si esta en la base de datos, pero al momento de consultar me aparece como NO Existe.

[image: esta es la interfaz y la ejecuccion del programa]

[image: este es el dato en la base de datos]

el problema que detecto es:
. que no me esta llegando el documento para la consulta.

muchas gracias por su tiempo y espero me puedan colaborar, soy novato en esto.

Comment: Probaste imprimir en consola el valor del input? Prueba reemplazar `$("#asignarDocumento").attr("value");` por  `$("#asignarDocumento").val();`

Comment: .val() imprime el valor que hay en esa variable? lo reemplazo y no ocasiona cambios me sigue apareciendo que no se encuentra en la base de datos

Comment: no, obtiene el valor del input. para saber si esta obteniendo el valor puedes usar un alert. Por ejemplo `alert($("#asignarDocumento").val())`

Comment: no genera ningun valor con alert($("#asignarDocumento").val()).

Comment: En el código no te aseguras en ningún momento que la consulta devuelve datos, puede que el criterio no se cumpla y devuelva un conjunto de resultados vacío. En este tipo de casos siempre hay que verificar el estado de los datos y si no hay datos indicarlo de alguna manera. Incluso, deberías verificar también si la conexión y la consulta son válidas. Todo eso falta en tu código. Es un código *azucarado*, escrito pensando que en la vida todo irá siempre bien. Aquí al menos tres errores pueden ocurrir y tienes que controlarlos los tres.

Comment: ok acepto tu comentario A-cedano por eso me guio en personas que saben mas que yo como tu tal parece, a lo relacionado con la consulta ya esta verificada, a la conexion ya he hecho insercciones y consultas asi que en cuanto a la clase conexion no deberia ser, mi punto es que el problema es en la obtenccion de los datos, el problema es como verificar si esta llegando el documento a la consulta.

Comment: En tu PHP tienes dos funciones, pero esas funciones parece que ninguna es llamada. Tampoco veo donde recuperas los datos que son pasados. Deberías tener algo así, donde verifiques el POST y llames a la función: `if(isset($_POST["consultarPaciente")) { echo consultarPaciente($_POST["documento"]); } else { echo "No se posteó ninguna acción definida";}` O sea, cuando mandas algo por POST a `index.php` (que es el controlador, supongo), debes verificar en ese archivo lo que se está posteando hacia él, sea con `isset`  o con otro método y llamar entonces las funciones adecuadas.

Comment: Listo ya subi la pgina principal donde llamo las acciones de la pagina se llama index,php desde alli llamo la clase controlador, desde la clase controlador llamo la clase gestor cita.

Comment: Index.php es la principal, en esta verifico cual es la acción necesaria, en este caso  es consultarpaciente, de ahí llamo la clase controlador, de esta llamo gestorcita y este retorna la consulta. Lo que necesito saber como imprimir o saber si la variable documento tiene algún valor.

Answer (score 0):

No esta devolviendo el valor, por que no lo encuentra, eso se debe a que la consulta esta mal, ya sea que no se esta obteniendo el valor del input o no se esta pasando, en tu codigo no estas haciendo las comprobaciones o dandole un seguimiento a tu flujo de informacion para verificar si el valor del input es el introducido en tu consulta sql, ahora suponiendo que el valor deseado llega a la consulta de sql, al remplazar el valor tu string toma como valor a buscar '$doc', no el valor de la variable $doc
En tu consulta SQL

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Pacientes WHERE pacIdentificacion = '$doc' ";
```

Remplaza

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM Pacientes WHERE pacIdentificacion = '".$doc."' ";
```

Comment: por que esta es la solución? recuerda siempre agregar una explicación